# Nifi path is invalid

Tags: apache-nifi

I am running a Nifi server, basically I have a ListFile running perfectly OK in this path : /tmp/nifi/info/daily. Here I can work and run the processor without any issue.

Because an specific reason, I had to create another ListFile, which its information is on the path: /tmp/nifi/info/last_month. When I add this second value, it says the path doesn't exist.

I checked the permissions with an ls -l, they are exactly the same, and same group:user, so I'm confused:

```
drwxr-xr-x. 2 nifi hadoop
```

I even tried re-starting Nifi to see if it was that but not. Is there any way I can test (other than keep trying input paths in the config) to see which access Nifi have? Why it doesn't see the folder?

Thanks.

Comment: It's definitely not a permissions issue since you get a "PathNotFoundException"(as I understand).

`ListFile` works on local filesystem. Could you provide the processor's configuration?

Comment: @BenYaakobi I think I fixed it, we are running Nifi in two servers, the folder structure has to be exact on both instances where Nifi is running. Does it ring a bell?

Comment: Of course, since it is working on your local filesystem on each node..

Answer (score 2):

As @Ben Yaakobi mentioned I was missing to create the folder on every node.